# How do I simply embed HTML into a layout/template in Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

I am just starting out with Scala and Lift and I apologize ahead of time about this pretty basic question but how do I "import" or rather embed HTML file into a layout/template?

Basically I have a bunch of layouts and each of them has hard coded footer. I want to extract footer into a separate HTML and then reference it back in all layout files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "starting" template for Lift: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/

In Lift Basic https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/tree/master/scala_210/lift_basic  you can see an example of a footer that can be put around many other HTML-s: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_210/lift_basic/src/main/webapp/templates-hidden/default.html

To use this footer, you access it like in https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_210/lift_basic/src/main/webapp/index.html  :

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
```

Another link to read about this: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.3.html#toc-Subsection-3.3.3

BTW, starting with the lift_basic github template is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to pull in an HTML file, like a footer, you can use the `embed` snippet, as specified [here](http://demo.liftweb.net/templating/embed).

So, if you have a file in the root of your webapp named `footer.html`, you can embed it with this code:

```
<div data-lift="embed?what=/footer"></div>
```

The templating engine will also allow you to use other directives like [`surround`](http://demo.liftweb.net/templating/surround) if you want to insert content at a particular point in the middle of an existing HTML file.